# How to add encrypted variables in codemagic.yaml?

Tags: codemagic

I'm new to Codemagic, and I want to use it to automatically build, test and deploy my Flutter app.

Following [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/AdZGj8ZVSyo?t=1035), I would like to encrypt some variables and add them in my `codemagic.yaml` file, using the Encrypt environnement variables utility, as shown in the tutorial.

But it looks like it's an old interface, and I can't find it anywhere anymore.

So how can I encrypt sensitive variables and add them in my `codemagic.yaml` file, using the `Encrypted()` command?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Encrypted()` variables were deprecated time ago and now you should add all secret variables in Codemagic UI. You can read more here https://docs.codemagic.io/yaml-basic-configuration/configuring-environment-variables/